# Can't import the named export 'Keypair' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, solana, solana-web3js

I am trying to build a react app that is used to mint NFTs. I've imported classes from web3.js and spl-token. I have an issue when importing the Keypair class from web3.js. My code is given below.

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MintToken from './mint-token';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <MintToken/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**mint-token.tsx**
mint-token is used to create a wallet and mint a token.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  clusterApiUrl,
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  Keypair,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
} from '@solana/web3.js';
import {
  createMint,
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
  mintTo,
  transfer,
  Account,
  getMint,
  getAccount
} from '@solana/spl-token';

//Special setup to add a buffer class, because it's missing
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;

function MintToken() {

  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'),'confirmed'); //JSON RPC API connection creation
  const fromWallet = Keypair.generate();
  let mint: PublicKey;
  let fromTokenAccount: Account;

  async function createToken(){
    const fromAirdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(fromWallet.publicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL); //Airdrop SOLs to the wallet to minting
    await connection.confirmTransaction(fromAirdropSignature);

    //Creating a new token
    mint = await createMint(    
      connection,
      fromWallet,
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      null,
      9
    )
    console.log('Create token: ${mint.toBase58()}');

    //Get the token account of the fromWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
    fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      fromWallet,
      mint,
      fromWallet.publicKey
    );
    console.log('Create Token Account: ${fromTokenAccount.address.toBase58()}');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      Mint Token Section
        <div>
            <button onClick={createToken}>Create Token</button>
            <button>Mint Token</button>
            <button>Check Balance</button>
            <button>Send Token</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MintToken;
```

I get an error:

> ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token/lib/esm/actions/createMint.mjs
> Can't import the named export 'Keypair' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: I found the solution to this issue. FIX: connect the right wallet with the correct keypair!